# Facebook access token in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

Which is the right approach to get access token for Facebook in iOS app?

1. Using Facebook app
2. Using safari
3. USing inline dialog

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the Facebook api for iOS you need only ask it to authorize. It will actually check if your device support multitasking. If so, it will first try to use Facebook app. If it will fall(as the app might be not installed on that device after all), it will proceed to safari. And if you are on non-multitasking device it will open an inline dialog popup.
Just use the last version and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

it's done automatically

it used to be that facebook authentication would always open a uiwebview to opt the user to enter his credentials.

But now - if your ios version supports multitasking - it will open the facebook app or safari if possible and ask for authorization and then redirect back to your application. for more information you should refer to the sample application of the facebook sdk.

So it will try 1 then 2 and then fallback to 3

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I think better will be to use UIWebView or ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: You would say last option (web-view showing in the App) is the better approach?

Comment: Not showing, you can just get content from UIWebView and parse it. I get acesstoken in vk.com social network with UIWebView. It's hidden on my UIView. If you'll use this, you will need to implement UIWebViewDelegate methods, to handle when page loads, and when to get the acesstoken.